# inorder traversal modified for range query in BST prolog

Tags: prolog, binary-search-tree

This is the pretty known code for an inorder traversal in a generic binary tree in PROLOG:

```
inorder(t(K,L,R), List) :-
    inorder(L,LL), inorder(R, LR), 
    append(LL, [K|LR], List). 
    inorder(nil, []).
```

if the input binary tree is a binary search tree (BST), what about If I want to modify such code in such way I will not visit just all the nodes, but only the minimum needed to find those ones whose key falls in a given range, having them as output result?

I am trying something like:

```
inorder(R1, R2, t(K,L,R), List) :-
    (K >= R1 -> inorder(R1, R2, L, LL); true),
    (K =< R2 -> inorder(R1, R2, R, LR); true),
    append(LL, [K|LR], List).

inorder(_, _, _, _).
```

I figured out the correct version:

```
inorder(R1,R2, t(K,L,R), List) :-
(   R2 < K
->  inorder(R1,R2, L, LL),
append(LL,[],List);
    K < R1
->  inorder(R1,R2, R, LR),
append(LR,[],List);
    inorder(R1,R2, L, LL),
    inorder(R1,R2, R, LR),
    append(LL, [K|LR], List)
).
```

Comment: What happens when you try this? How is it wrong?

Comment: I updated the post. Look above

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: I wonder how you can be sure that's *correct* ? And please, acknowledge that was *my* solution, before you 'patched' it.

Comment: Anyway, thanks to you for the question. It's interesting.

Comment: If u want to test that's correct, try with this BST t(6, t(4, t(2, nil, nil), t(5, nil, nil)), t(9, t(7, nil, nil), nil)). I will try to do that u asked

Answer (score 1):

you are 'near to target', and you will benefit of studying what your code does. Here is my solution (only minimally tested)

```
inorder(R1,R2, t(K,L,R), List) :-
    (   R2 < K
    ->  inorder(R1,R2, L, List)
    ;   K < R1
    ->  inorder(R1,R2, R, List)
    ;   inorder(R1,R2, L, LL),
        inorder(R1,R2, R, LR),
        append(LL, [K|LR], List)
    ).
inorder(_R1,_R2, -, []).
```

of course, I like best a DCG solution

```
inorder(R1,R2, Tree, Yield) :-
    phrase(inorder(R1, R2, Tree), Yield, []).

inorder(R1,R2, t(K,L,R)) -->
        {R2 < K}
    ->  inorder(R1,R2,L)
    ;   {K < R1}
    ->  inorder(R1,R2,R)
    ;   inorder(R1,R2,L),
        [K],
        inorder(R1,R2,R).
inorder(_R1,_R2, -) --> [].
```

note: no more append/3 needed. It's cleaner and more efficient.

*edit* better naming:

```
inorder(R1,R2, Tree, Yield) :-
    phrase(rangequery(R1, R2, Tree), Yield, []).

rangequery(R1,R2, t(K,L,R)) -->
        {R2 < K}
    ->  rangequery(R1,R2,L)
    ;   {K < R1}
    ->  rangequery(R1,R2,R)
    ;   rangequery(R1,R2,L),
        [K],
        rangequery(R1,R2,R).
rangequery(_R1,_R2, -) --> [].
```

and sample run

```
?- inorder(1,2,t(3,t(1,-,-),-),L).
L = [1] ;
false.

?- inorder(1,4,t(3,t(1,-,t(2,-,-)),-),L).
L = [1, 2, 3] ;
false.
```

Comment: I developed your first hint and turned into a correct solution. I don't know anything about DCG so for now I will be satisfied with about the first classical solution.

Comment: +1 for a nice DGC. `phrase(NT, List, [])` is equivalent to `phrase(NT, List)`.

Comment: @mat: thanks. rangequery seems useful to aggregate structured domains. About phrase: I know, just was playing with semi-context expansion, and forgot to remove the useless [].